# Wrong language flag

Tags: support

It's clear that [answers in the wrong language](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22944/can-a-110v-spa-pump-curcuit-control-a-220v-spa-heater-that-is-on-its-own-220v-c#comment109143_57471) have to be flagged. But should they get flagged as not an answer, very low quality, spam, not welcome or other?

I marked this one as other with the note "Wrong language".

Comment: You are over-thinking this.

Comment: I know, I'm an over-thinker :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not an answer, I dont have a strong preference and your flag will be marked as valid regardless which you pick.